# How do I create new columns by combining data in existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that includes 5 columns Excuse formatting:

```
id     Price    Service Rater Name  Cleanliness
401013357   5   3   A   1
401014972   2   1   A   5
401022510   3   4   B   2
401022510   5   1   C   9
401022510   3   1   D   4
401022510   2   2   E   2
```

I would like for there to be only one row for each ID.  Therefore, I need to create columns for each of the raters' names and ratings categories (e.g. Rater Name Price, Rater Name Service, Rater name Cleanliness), each in its own column.  Thank you.

I've explored groupby but cannot figure out how to manipulate these into new columns.  Thank you!

```
Here's the code and data I'm actually using:

import requests
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd


linesinfo_url = 'https://api.collegefootballdata.com/lines?year=2018&seasonType=regular'
linesresp = requests.get(linesinfo_url)

dflines = DataFrame(linesresp.json())
#nesteddata in lines like game info
#setting game ID as index
dflines.set_index('id', inplace=True)

a = linesresp.json()
#defining a as the response to our get request for this data, in JSON format 
buf = []
#i believe this creates a receptacle for nested data I'm extracting from json
for game in a:
    for line in game['lines']:
        game_dict = dict(id=game['id'])
        for cat in ('provider', 'spread','formattedSpread', 'overUnder'):
           game_dict[cat] = line[cat]
        buf.append(game_dict)

dflinestable = pd.DataFrame(buf)
dflinestable.set_index(['id', 'provider'])
```

From this, I get

```
                              formattedSpread  overUnder  spread
id        provider                                                
401013357 consensus                   UMass -21       68.0   -21.0
401014972 consensus                  Rice -22.5       58.5   -22.5
401022510 Caesars          Colorado State -17.5       57.5   -17.5
          consensus          Colorado State -17       57.5   -17.0
          numberfire         Colorado State -17       58.5   -17.0
          teamrankings       Colorado State -17       58.0   -17.0
401013437 numberfire                 Wyoming -5       47.0     5.0
          teamrankings               Wyoming -5       47.0     5.0
401020671 consensus            Ball State -19.5       61.5   -19.5
401019470 Caesars                     UCF -22.5        NaN    22.5
          consensus                   UCF -22.5        NaN    22.5
          numberfire                    UCF -24       70.0    24.0
          teamrankings                  UCF -24       70.0    24.0
401013328 numberfire            Minnesota -21.5       47.0   -21.5
          teamrankings          Minnesota -21.5       49.0   -21.5
```

The outcome I am looking for is for each of the 4 different providers to have three columns each, so that it's caesars_formattedSpread, caesars_overUnder, Caesars spread, numberfire_formattedSpread, numberfire_overUnder, numberfire_spread, etc.

When I run unstack as suggested, I don't get what I expect.  Instead I get:

```
formattedSpread  0                  UMass -21
                 1                 Rice -22.5
                 2       Colorado State -17.5
                 3         Colorado State -17
                 4         Colorado State -17
                 5         Colorado State -17
                 6                 Wyoming -5
                 7                 Wyoming -5
                 8           Ball State -19.5
                 9                  UCF -22.5
                 10                 UCF -22.5
                 11                   UCF -24
                 12                   UCF -24
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: What have you tried and what is the expected result? Can you please provide more information!

Comment: @WeNYoBen  - see edits.

Comment: @SimonFink I've made major edits as indicated above.  Was probably trying to oversimplify.

Comment: Late to the party but what's the expected output? I only see an "incorrect" output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** Edited, based on the edited question ***

Given that your dataframe is `df`:

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'Rater Name']) # Make it a Multi Index
df_unstacked = df.unstack()
```

The problem with your edited code, is that you don't assign `dflinestable.set_index(['id', 'provider'])` to anything. So when you then use `dflinestable.unstack()`, you are unstacking the original `dflinestable`.

So with your entire code, it should be:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


linesinfo_url = 'https://api.collegefootballdata.com/lines?year=2018&seasonType=regular'
linesresp = requests.get(linesinfo_url)

dflines = pd.DataFrame(linesresp.json())
#nesteddata in lines like game info
#setting game ID as index
dflines.set_index('id', inplace=True)

a = linesresp.json()
#defining a as the response to our get request for this data, in JSON format 
buf = []
#i believe this creates a receptacle for nested data I'm extracting from json
for game in a:
    for line in game['lines']:
        game_dict = dict(id=game['id'])
        for cat in ('provider', 'spread','formattedSpread', 'overUnder'):
           game_dict[cat] = line[cat]
        buf.append(game_dict)

dflinestable = pd.DataFrame(buf)
dflinestable.set_index(['id', 'provider'], inplace=True) # Add inplace=True
dflinestable_unstacked = dflinestable.unstack() # unstack (you could also reassign to the same df

# Flatten columns to single level, in the order as described
dflinestable_unstacked.columns = [f'{j}_{i}' for i, j in dflinestable_unstacked.columns]
```

This will give you a DataFrame like (abbreviated):

```
          Caesars_formattedSpread  ... teamrankings_spread
id                                 ...                    
401012246             Alabama -24  ...               -23.5
401012247            Arkansas -34  ...                 NaN
401012248               Auburn -1  ...                -1.5
401012249                     NaN  ...                 NaN
401012250             Georgia -44  ...                 NaN
```

Comment: think I finally started to get the hang of the formatting of the question at least -- see above.  Not quite solved yet.

Comment: The problem is that you don't reassign 'df.set_index()` to anything. So you then unstack the df with the original index. See the edited code above.

Comment: Tremendously helpful.  Thank you.